# Can Anyone ID This Rose?

Tags: identification

I apologize, this is not a good photo but it’s the only one I have. I’m looking for this rose that was planted in the mid-late 1990s or very early 2000s. This was an upright bush that didn’t spread. It is shown at its mature height of about 30” and spread
Of maybe 24.” It used to bloom into December here along the the northeast US coast. It was my mother’s favorite & didn’t survive transplanting after she died. 
Thank you. [image]